# Replace multiple indexes with one value

Tags: go, replace

I have an array that has the value

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

I want to replace indexes 1  to 3, `[2, 3, 4]`, with the single value of 123.
Is there a way to do this in golang?

Comment: Yes, but there is no built-in solution for this. You have to write it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than use an array you should be working with slices.

```
        a := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
        b := append(append(a[:1:1], 123), a[4:]...)
```

Or if you don't need to keep the original elements then copy in place.

```
        a := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
        a[1] = 123
        copy(a[2:8], a[4:10])
        a = a[:8]
```